# check every random number in sudoku (java)

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, solver, sudoku, game-theory

i have the code below which solve the sudoku by check every random number if is not duplicate in the sudoku but doesn't work & i think it goes in infinite loop because it doesn't show any result ,  if my method is completly false please tell me about the right way and edit the code for me please .

```
 package essai;

import java.util.Random;

public class Essai_checker {

    static final boolean valide=true;
    static final boolean non_valide=false;

    //check number if not deplicate in row or colomn or sub grid 
static boolean checkInt(int a[][],int test,int c_i,int c_j){

        if(test==0) return non_valide;

        //check ligne
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
            if(test==a[c_i][i]) return non_valide;
        }
        //check colomn
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
            if(test==a[i][c_j]) return non_valide;
        }

        //check sub_grid

        int ii=c_i/3;
        int jj=c_j/3;
        // this test are for telling wich sub-grid contain the number 
        if(ii<3) c_i=0; 
        else 
            if(ii>1 && ii<2) c_i=3;     
            else if(ii>2 && ii<=3) c_i=6;

        if(jj<3) c_j=0;
        else 
            if(jj>1 && jj<2) c_j=3;     
            else if(jj>2 && jj<=3) c_j=6;

        for(int i=c_i;i<c_i+3;i++){
            for(int j=c_j;j<c_j+3;j++){
                if(test==a[c_i][c_j]) return non_valide;
            }
        }
            return valide;
        }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [][] soduko2={
                {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
            };
        Random r=new Random();
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<9;j++){
                int entier=r.nextInt(9)+1;
                boolean init =checkInt(soduko2,entier,i,j);
                while(init ==non_valide){
                    entier=r.nextInt(9);
                    init =checkInt(soduko2,entier,i,j);
                }
                if(init=true)
                    soduko2[i][j]=entier;
            }
            }
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<9;j++){
                System.out.println(soduko2[i][j]+",");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Done!");

    }

}
```

Comment: -1 "please tell me about the write way and edit the code for me please " - "the right way", and editing code the way you want isn't the way SO works

Comment: The problem is with your board filling algorithm. The way you fill can leave you at the end where there no possibly valid values available for a given square. In that case, your program is going to be stuck generating random numbers, none of which will ever work. You need a better algorithm

Comment: i don't think so , because it test all sudoko every time

Comment: i know that there is a an AG method but i don't want to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, The condition `(ii>1 && ii<2)` will always be false , dunno if this can be a problem

Second, The condition `(ii>2 && ii<=3)` will only be true if `ii==3`

Maybe this will be part of the problem

Comment: i make the sub-grid check in comment and the same problem